# Update page after successful insertion into MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, updates

I am making a page that has a bunch of fields that allows the user to enter in information and submit it to a database. This page is called 'add.php' I created a 'form' tag and had the information posted to another page called 'process.php' where the information is collected, then inserted into the database. I want the user to know whether it was successful or not, so I was wondering how to tell the user something specific on the 'add.php' page. like "insertion successful!" at the top of the page.

I thought of including the 'process.php' code in 'add.php', then calling the 'add.php' in the action of the form, but the code gets called the first time the page is loaded, which inserts a completely blank entry into the database.

Should I implement some sort of flag that is only set to true after the 'submit' button is clicked? Or is there another way to update the page and tell the user the status of the insertion?

I can paste the relevant code as needed. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the `post` method in your form and php, you can simply check if a post was made:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
  // form was posted, process and display output
}
else
{
  // nothing was posted, normal get request, show form
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I just have an include in the form.php and the form page calls itself in the action. It checks for the post, and includes the processing if a post was made. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

just check if query worked well. If no exception was thrown, it mostly has, and the add appropriate message with output.

First you need to check and handle errors

```
try
{

} 
catch(Exception $e){
header('Location:oldlocation.php?succ=0')
exit();
}
header('Location:oldlocation.php?succ=0')
exit();
```

If all goes well, you can also redirect to a new location(as shown in code). This has to be done properly, you may redirect back to the old location, with additional data like

```
oldlocation.php?succ=1;
```

If anything goes wrong redirect to

```
oldlocation.php?succ=0
```

Then fetch the succ using $_GET["succ"] and print appropriate message.

If you din get, comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do...
Keep your processing data in one file, and include the form file at the end

```
//add.php

//if the form is submitted make the database entry
if(isset($_POST['foo']) AND $_POST['foo'] != '')
{
//code to process form submission
$success = 'success!';

}
//include the form
include addform.php
```

in addform.php put your form. Include an 'isset' that is watching for $success to alert that the entry was successful

```
//addform.php

<?php if(isset($success)){ echo "<h2> Data successfully entered! </h2>";} ?>

<form action='' method='POST'>
<input type='text' name='foo' />
//etc
</form>
```

So once you submit the form, the code starts at the top of add.php - the 'isset' sees the $_POST submission, runs the form submission code and sets the success variable. Then, it includes the form page. The form page has an 'isset' that is watching for the success variable. When you first navigate to the page, or if you refresh, the add.php code will skip the first code block (the form submission stuff) and won't make a database submission or set the success variable.